# RequireJS 2.1.9 causing "Maximum call stack.." error when using Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I am using Grunt to build a multi-module application (Backbone, Marionette, RequireJS, Handlebars) but I keep getting the "Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" message. If I replace the r.js 2.1.9 file with 2.1.5, it works. I don't have a clue where to even start debugging.

Note: Running the same build config options right from node does work with 2.1.9

```
node r.js -o build.js
```

It just doesn't like running from Grunt.

r.js 2.1.9

grunt-cli v0.1.11

grunt v0.4.2

**Here is my Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                appDir: "src/main/webapp",
                baseUrl: 'js/',
                dir: "target",
                mainConfigFile: 'src/main/webapp/js/require-config.js',

                //optimizeAllPluginResources : true,
                findNestedDependencies: true,
                //removeCombined : true,
                //optimize : 'none',
                //inlineText : true,
                modules: [{
                    name: "main",
                    excludeShallow: ["config"],
                    override: {
                        paths: {
                            "shipping-address": "empty:",
                            "shipping-method": "empty:",
                            "payment-method": "empty:",
                            "place-order": "empty:",
                            "order-confirmation": "empty:",
                            "quote": "empty:"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'shipping-address',
                    exclude: ["main", "config"],
                    override: {
                        paths: {
                            "shipping-method": "empty:"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'shipping-method',
                    exclude: ["main", "config", 'shipping-address'],
                    override: {
                        paths: {
                            "payment-method": "empty:"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'payment-method',
                    exclude: ["main", "config", 'shipping-address', 'shipping-method'],
                    override: {
                        paths: {
                            "place-order": "empty:"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'place-order',
                    exclude: ["main", "config", 'shipping-address', 'shipping-method', 'payment-method'],
                    override: {
                        paths: {
                            "order-confirmation": "empty:"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'order-confirmation',
                    exclude: ["main", "config", 'shipping-address', 'shipping-method', 'payment-method', 'place-order']
                }, {
                    name: 'quote',
                    exclude: ["main", "config"]
                }],

                //stubModules: ['hbs', 'checkout-controller'],

                preserveLicenseComments: false,

                pragmasOnSave: {
                    //removes Handlebars.Parser code (used to compile template strings) set
                    //it to `false` if you need to parse template strings even after build
                    excludeHbsParser: true,
                    // kills the entire plugin set once it's built.
                    excludeHbs: true,
                    // removes i18n precompiler, handlebars and json2
                    excludeAfterBuild: true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    handlebars: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                namespace: "JST"
            },
            files: [{
                src: ['src/main/webapp/templates/**/*.html'],
                dest: 'dest/out.js'
            }]
        }
    },

    concat: {
        options: {},
        dist: {
            src: ["src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/parts/Header/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js", "src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/parts/Header/js/respond.src.js", 'src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'src/main/webapp/js/arrow.min.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        options: {},
        'dist': {
            src: ["src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/parts/Header/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js", "src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/parts/Header/js/respond.src.js", 'src/main/webapp/brands/arrow/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'src/main/webapp/js/arrow.min.js'
        }
    },

    jshint: {
        files: ['src/main/webapp/js/**/*.js', '!src/main/webapp/js/**/libs/**'],
        options: {
            // Settings
            "passfail": false, // Stop on first error.
            "maxerr": 50, // Maximum error before stopping.

            // Predefined globals whom JSHint will ignore.
            "browser": true, // Standard browser globals e.g. `window`, `document`.
            "couch": false,
            "dojo": false,
            "jquery": true,
            "mootools": false,
            "node": false,
            "prototypejs": false,
            "rhino": false,
            "wsh": false,

            // Custom globals.
            "predef": ["define", "require"],

            // Development.
            "debug": false, // Allow debugger statements e.g. browser breakpoints.
            "devel": false, // Allow developments statements e.g. `console.log();`.

            // EcmaScript 5.
            "es5": false, // Allow EcmaScript 5 syntax.
            "globalstrict": false, // Allow global "use strict" (also enables 'strict').
            "strict": false, // Require `use strict` pragma in every file.

            // The Good Parts.
            "asi": false, // Tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion (no semicolons).
            "bitwise": false, // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
            "boss": true, // Tolerate assignments inside if, for & while. Usually conditions & loops are for comparison, not assignments.
            "curly": false, // Require {} for every new block or scope.
            "eqeqeq": true, // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
            "eqnull": true, // Tolerate use of `== null`.
            "evil": false, // Tolerate use of `eval`.
            "expr": false, // Tolerate `ExpressionStatement` as Programs.
            "forin": false, // Tolerate `for in` loops without `hasOwnPrototype`.
            "immed": true, // Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `( function(){}() );`
            "latedef": false, // Prohibit variable use before definition.
            "laxbreak": false, // Tolerate unsafe line breaks e.g. `return [\n] x` without semicolons.
            "loopfunc": false, // Allow functions to be defined within loops.
            "noarg": true, // Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`.
            "regexdash": true, // Tolerate unescaped last dash i.e. `[-...]`.
            "regexp": false, // Prohibit `.` and `[^...]` in regular expressions.
            "scripturl": false, // Tolerate script-targeted URLs.
            "shadow": false, // Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. `var x=1; x=2;`.
            "supernew": false, // Tolerate `new function () { ... };` and `new Object;`.
            "undef": false, // Require all non-global variables be declared before they are used.

            // Personal styling prefrences.
            "newcap": true, // Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`.
            "noempty": true, // Prohipit use of empty blocks.
            "nomen": false, // Prohibit use of initial or trailing underbars in names.
            "nonew": true, // Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects.
            "onevar": false, // Allow only one `var` statement per function.
            "plusplus": false, // Prohibit use of `++` & `--`.
            "sub": false, // Tolerate all forms of subscript notation besides dot notation e.g. `dict['key']` instead of `dict.key`.
            "trailing": true, // Prohibit trailing whitespaces.
            "white": false // Check against strict whitespace and indentation rules.
        },

    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-tools');

//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
//grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'qunit']);

grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);
};
```

**Here is my require-config.js**

```
define('require-config', ["console"], function() {

var toAbsolutePath = function(url) {
    var loc = location.href;
    loc = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
    while (/^\.\./.test(url)) {
        loc = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
        url = url.substring(3);
    }
    return loc + '/' + url;
};

var parseQueryString = function(query) {
    if (query.indexOf("?") == 0) {
        query = query.substr(1);
    }

    var a = query.split('&');
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var p = a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2)
            continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
};

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
require.config({
    paths : {
        jquery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-require',
        underscore : 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        backbone : 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        "backbone.marionette" : 'libs/backbone/backbone.marionette',
        bootstrap : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap',
        alert : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert',
        datePicker : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker',
        paginator : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-paginator',
        templates : '../templates',
        'jquery.ui.widget' : 'libs/jqueryui/jquery.ui.widget',
        iframetransport : 'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.iframe-transport-custom',
        viewstack : 'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.jquery-viewstack',
        xdrtransport : "libs/cors/jquery.xdr-transport",
        dropdown : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.dropdown",
        scrollTo : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min",
        fileupload : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.fileupload",
        i18n : "libs/jquery/plugins/i18n",
        modalPop : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.simplemodal-custom",
        payment : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.payment",
        printThis : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.printThis",
        placeholder : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.placeholder.1.3.min",
        highlight : "libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui-highlight.min",
        BaseClass : "base-class",
        apis : "apis",
        fixture : 'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.fixture',
        UserModel : 'models/user-model',
        OrderModel : 'models/order-model',
        PendingSalesOrderModel : 'models/pending-sales-order-model',
        ShoppingCart : "collections/shopping-cart-collection",
        ShoppingCartItemModel : "models/shopping-cart-item-model",
        AddressItemModel : "models/address-item-model",
        catalogModel : "models/catalog-model",
        CreditLimitModel : "models/credit-limit-model",
        AddressCollection : "collections/address-collection",
        ShippingOptionCollection : "collections/shipping-option-collection",
        CountriesAndStatesCollection : "collections/countries-and-states-collection",
        OrderHistoryCollection : "collections/order-history-collection",
        "jquery.validate" : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.validate",
        "blockUI" : "libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.blockUI",
        handlebars : "libs/handlebars/handlebars",
        "handlebars.runtime" : "libs/handlebars/handlebars.runtime",
        hbs : "libs/handlebars/hbs",
        json2 : "libs/handlebars/json2",
        i18nprecompile : 'libs/handlebars/i18nprecompile',
        "backbone.marionette.handlebars" : "libs/handlebars/backbone.marionette.handlebars",
        "paypalHelper" : "paypal-helper",
        'accounting' : "libs/accounting",
        vent : "vent",
        addressVent : "addressVent",
        "CartDialog" : "views/shoppingcart/shoppingcart-item-update-dialog",
        config : "config",
        tracker : "tracker",
        "checkout-controller" : "controllers/checkout-controller",
        "shoppingcart-controller" : "controllers/shoppingcart-controller",
        "partquote-controller" : "controllers/partquote-controller",
        "shipping-address" : "views/checkout/shipping-address",
        "shipping-method" : "views/checkout/shipping-method",
        "payment-method" : "views/checkout/payment-method",
        "place-order" : "views/checkout/place-order",
        "order-confirmation" : "views/checkout/order-confirmation",
        "quote" : "views/quote/quote",
        "ecliptek" : "views/quote/ecliptek-quote"
    },

    shim : {
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },

        backbone : {
            deps : ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports : "Backbone"
        },

        "backbone.marionette" : {
            exports : 'Backbone.Marionette',
            deps : ['backbone']
        },
        "jquery.validate" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        "blockUI" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },
        'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab' : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },
        "libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },
        'arrowjs' : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        "libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        "libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker' : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-paginator' : {
         deps :['jquery']
        },

        'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert' : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        hbs : {
            deps : ['handlebars', 'json2', 'i18nprecompile']
        },

        "backbone.marionette.handlebars" : {
            deps : ["backbone.marionette"]
        },

        "colorAnimator" : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },
        scrollTo : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        },

        dropdown : {
            deps : ['jquery']
        }

    },

    deps : ["template_helper", "blockUI", "jquery.validate", "backbone.marionette", 'handlebars', "backbone.marionette.handlebars"],

    // default plugin settings, listing here just as a reference
    hbs : {
        templateExtension : 'html',
        // if disableI18n is `true` it won't load locales and the i18n helper
        // won't work as well.
        disableI18n : true,
        disableHelpers : true
    }
});

require.config({
    paths : {
        config : window ? toAbsolutePath("js/config") : "config"
    }
});
})
```

**Console Output**

```
Tracing dependencies for: main

    Tracing dependencies for: shipping-address

    Tracing dependencies for: shipping-method

    Tracing dependencies for: payment-method

    Tracing dependencies for: place-order

    Tracing dependencies for: order-confirmation

    Tracing dependencies for: quote

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    Tracing dependencies for: config

    { [Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

      originalError: [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded] }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you want to enable `findNestedDependencies: true,`? If your require.config is setup properly, there's actually no  such need.

Hope it helps.